# File get contents too slow on 50 files

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I need to copy existing private s3 files to another directory but my process is too slow, on my local its 2 seconds per file_get_content of each file.

My problem is most files that I process are 50+ files so if you total that would be 2seconds * 50 and its really not a great user experience waiting for that amount of time for a process to finish, what might be the best approach I can do to refactor this? queue is not really an option at the moment

```
foreach ($sourceAttachmentFiles as $sourceAttachmentFile) {

    $newFullFileName = $newDirectory.$sourceAttachmentFile->filename;
    
    // 2 seconds every loop
    $content = file_get_contents($sourceAttachmentFile->getS3SignedUrl());

    Storage::disk('s3')->put($newFullFileName, $content, 'private');
}
```

Comment: "queue is not really an option at the moment" It's really your primary option.

Comment: i agree. unless there are some batch commands on AWS S3 API, and the files are organized in a way so you don't have to iterate over each; A nice progress bar animation might help pass the time. But in general, a queue is asynchronous. If you want the user to be aware of what's happening as its happening, you should show them. If they don't care, maybe notify them when the queue is done?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, but your code seems to be downloading the file contents and then uploading it again. Can it possibly make use of the Amazon S3 `CopyObject()` command? That does not involve any download/upload.